# Show UTF-16 smileys in Qt

Tags: qt, utf-16

Please help me show the *UTF-16 emoji* "**SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH**" as  from string "\uD83D\uDE03" in Qt (maybe use `qDebug()` or `QLabel` to show it).

I have:

```
QString a = "\\uD83D\\uDE03";
```

I want to print it into my `qDebug`, and the result I expected is . I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Could you please show your code? What have you tried?

Comment: I have `QString a = "\\uD83D\\uDE03";` I want to print it into my qDebug, and the result I expected is . I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After seen a comment (I've moved it to question):

> I have QString a = "\uD83D\uDE03"; I want to print it into my qDebug, and the result I expected is . I don't know how to do this.

I see what is the problem. String encoding and conversion between different types of string encoding.

When you have this kind of literal "\uD83D\uDE03" (leave it that it is invalid) you have to use encoding which can use single byte as character.
So for example UTF-8. Then you have to do conversion to `QString` which internally uses UTF-16.

To fix it (in Qt 5):

```
QString smile = QString::fromUtf8("\xF0\x9F\x98\x83");
```

In Qt 4  it is a bit more complex:

```
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
QString smile = QTextDecoder(codec).toUnicode("\xF0\x9F\x98\x83", 4);
```

Another approach uses `QChar` and it is [nicely documented](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromRawData) (works for Qt4 and Qt5), here is a tweak of example from documentation:

```
static const QChar unicodeSmile[] = { 0xD83D, 0xDE03, 0 };
QString smile = QString::fromRawData(unicodeSmile);
```

Note that there is also `wchar` but this is very platform depended, so it might create more problems (that it why Qt provided `QChar *` approach).